# How to set property as one type and get as another?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public class TaskDetails
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _arguments;
    public string Arguments
    {
        get
        {
            string _tmp = "";
            foreach (var _item in _arguments)
            {
                string _str = _item.Key + ": " + _item.Value + "<br>";
                _tmp += String.Join(_str, Environment.NewLine);
            }
            return _tmp;
        }
        set { _arguments = value;  }
    }
}
```

The idea is very simple: I **put** value into property in the form I'm comfortable with **up the code** (i.e. Dictionary), but I **get** it from property in the form for representation **down the code** - the string.

But IDE says about **set accessor** that I *cannot implicitly convert type string to Dictionary*. Silly IDE, I want to put in Dictionary into Dictionary-type private property.

How, then, should I do it to publicly set property as Dictionary and publicly get this property as string?

Comment: You cannot. But you could provide a second property (or a method) to set the Dictionary field.

Comment: You could make the private field a public property instead, with a private getter and a public setter, and give it a different name. But **why?** How about just have the dictionary property be publicly gettable and settable? You're not hiding anything by making the dictionary property not gettable...

Comment: You could change the `set` of `Arguments` to parse the `value` string and create the dictionary from it (if it's applicable). This way `Arguments` will serve as a "string" interface for the dictionary.

Comment: Would you expect to have a *variable* which is of one type when reading, but a different type when writing? If not, why would you expect to be able to do that for a property? No, you can't do this - and it's certainly not a matter of a "silly IDE". It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but I'd probably move the "getter" code into a method, e.g. `FormatArguments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of representing a dictionary as a `<br>` delimited set of plaintext strings is a little unusual and will probably need tweaks at some point in the future (e.g. if you wanted to put the text into `div` elements to make them valid HTML5, or if you wanted to provide escaping to prevent XSS, or you might want to use CRLF instead of `Environment.Newline` to match the HTTP protocol). So I'd suggest you encapsulate that idea in a class of its own. This will improve your maintainability.

Then you can give you custom class some implicit conversion operators, and you can write code that automatically converts to/from string or dictionary, allowing you to code it the way you were thinking (even though it's doing something slightly different under the covers).

```
public class HtmlDictionary //Or some other name
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _arguments;

    public HtmlDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> arguments)
    {
        _arguments = arguments;
    }
 
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string tmp = "";
        foreach (var item in arguments)
        {
            string str = $"{item.Key}: {item.Value}<br>\r\n";
            tmp += str;
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(HtmlDictionary input) => input.ToString();

    public static implicit operator HtmlDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> input) => new HtmlDictionary(input);
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
public class TaskDetails
{
    public HtmlDictionary Arguments { get; set }
}

var o = new TaskDetails();
o.Arguments = new Dictionary<string,string>();
string s = o.Arguments;
```

It looks like you are setting a different type than you are getting, but under the covers the compiler is just implicitly converting for you.

P.S. The underscore generally precedes member variables only. It will confuse a lot of people if you put an underscore in front of local variable names too.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. What's for part with "implicit operator"? Never done this before

Comment: [User-defined conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Comment: What does mean statements like those in human words? Like if you tried to explain it to child?

Comment: Just like a class has methods you can call by name, it has operators you can call by using a symbol (`==`, `+`, `*`, or the `(cast)` operator, to name a few). You can write code for those too. `implicit operator` is how you declare code for the implicit cast operation, which has no symbol (since it's implicit).

Comment: Ok, thank you! That helps. So the first line means that when I cast an object (which shall be accessible in second part of statement by the name of "input") of class HtmlDictionary as string (by assigning it to string variable later in code) I actually execute overridden version of ToString() method of same class over the same object by referring it as "input", right?

Comment: Exactly! I think you understand.